# Taylor expansion error understanding?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, taylor-expansion, signal-processing

I have a taylor expansion models as below. Can someone help me to understand the following plot? In the plot for A0 model, the plot is shifted towards right, which I understand. But with A1 model, I expected that the result will improve due to more terms in expansion, but the A1 model is overestimating. I could not understand, why this happens.

f(x) is a envelop of response of mass spring system. And I was trying to evaluate f(x-a).[image: f(x-a)]
zoom of the peak:[image: zoom on the peak]

$$f(t-a) \approx f(t)  :---  A0 $$

$$f(t-a) \approx f(t)-a*f'(t)  :---  A1 $$

$$f(t-a) \approx f(t)-a*f'(t) + \frac{a^2}{2}f''(t) :---  A2 $$

[taylor expansion plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpxNp.jpg)

Comment: I do not understand what you're plotting. Ordinarily in this scenario, you fix $t$ and then look at plots as $a$ varies. So in the linear case, you get a linear plot; in the quadratic case, you get a quadratic plot. So please say precisely what you're plotting.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Thanks for your reply. I have edited the question. f(x) is response of a system, which cannot be described like quadratic, or something else. It is random. I was trying to evaluate at f(x-a). As you pointed out, generally 'a' is varied to study the behaviour of taylor expansion. But if you consider for a certain 'a', if this how the plot looks.  What can be understood? I could not understand what exactly happens to A1... why it is very much over estimated?  Is it the beaviour of taylor to converge as number of terms increase?